# How to enable HTTPS using Goddady SSL in a Spring Boot application, deployed as WAR file in Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, tomcat, https, war

I have a Spring Boot application, deployed as WAR file in a Tomcat in Godaddy.Now, I do need to enable HTTPS on it.I had installed SSL on our domain and https is working on it.DNS and SSL certificates are managed by GoDaddy. I have already downloaded the certificate for tomcat which contains files as 'randomhex.crt','randomhex.pem','gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt','gdig2.crt.pem' and then I generated 'keystore.jks'&'keystore.p12' using these file following the below commands.

Step 1:

```
"keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias intermediate -file gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt -keystore keystore.jks"  using password as 'password1'
```

Step 2:

```
"keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias 'alias1' -file e1......7.crt -keystore keystore.jks"  using password as 'password1'
```

Step 3:

```
"keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.jks -destkeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype PKCS12 -deststorepass 'password2' -srcalias 'alias1' -destalias 'alias2'"   using password as 'password1'
```

I know now I need to add this 'keystore.p12' file to my springboot project 'resource' folder and set below ssl properties,but I am not sure about what value to set based on the above mentioned commands.Please help me to set the values for below,

```
server:
  ssl:
    key-store: classpath:keystore.p12
    key-store-password: ?
    key-store-type: ?
    key-alias: ?
    key-password: ?
    enabled: true
  port: ?
```

Also do I need to make anything on my TOMCAT server to make https work for this spring boot project???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.No need to configure SSL on spring boot.Just configure https on tomcat then https will work on your project.To configure https on tomcat you need to generate a keystore file(normally in .jks or .p12 format) by using sslcert.crt(randomhex.crt),sslkey.key,sslCA.crt(gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt) files as shown below:

goto '/opt/apache-tomcat/conf/' on your server and put above/below mentioned files there

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in mycert.crt -inkey mykey.key -out mycert.p12 -name tomcat -CAfile myCA.crt -caname root -chain
```

Here

'mycert.crt' -> your randomhex.crt file,

'mykey.key' -> SSL key file from godaddy,

'myCA.crt' ->  gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt ,

'mycert.p12' ->  Name of the keystore file you want to generate.

You should asked a password when running above command and remember that password to configure tomcat server.xml file.

Now open server.xml o tomcat conf folder in edit mode and add below connector there,after that exit and save changes and restart tomcat then https will start working on your project.

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" compression="on" scheme="https" secure="true" keystoreFile="conf/mycert.p12"
keystorePass="password" SSLVerifyClient="none" SSLProtocol="TLSv1.2" />
```

Don't forget to add port 8443 on your spring boot 'application.yml'

```
server:
   port: 8443
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this for Spring Boot:

```
server:
  ssl:
    key-store: classpath:keystore.p12
    key-store-password: password2
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-alias: alias2
    enabled: true
  port: 443
```

It does not look like a key-password is set. Try leaving it out & try 'changeit' (the default for jks).

For TOMCAT it needs to be set in $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml - one of the connectors:

```
<Connector
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           port="443" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="path/to/keystore.p12" keystorePass="password2" keyAlias="alias2"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Comment: Where should i put keystore.p12 on server??

Comment: I usually put in $TOMCAT_HOME/conf

Comment: I got below error after this  INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-443"]
SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-443]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:983)
        ....
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use .......

Comment: When I try the url I got following error   Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: The "java.net.BindException:" is because it was running, or something was running on that port.

Comment: The 404 is because the path you are calling with is not matched by one defined in a Controller. Not related to certs. If you got a 404 on an https call then your cert setup is good.

Comment: Do I need to add anything extra in my spring boot app to make https work??

Comment: No, you are getting SSL from TOMCAT.

Comment: earlier same url was working with http with port 8080.buts its not working with https with port as 443

Comment: same url is still  working in http with 8080 as port.Also the port 443 dissappear when i try the url