# 404 Not Found : after adding https to spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, tomcat, https

In my spring boot application I added ssl properties in application.yml as below:

```
server:
  ssl:
    key-store: classpath:keystore.p12
    key-store-password: password
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-alias: alias
    enabled: true
 port: 443
```

and the application war file has successfully deployed on tomcat server.Configured server.xml of tomcat as below for https:

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
keystoreFile="conf/keystore.p12" keystorePass="password" keyAlias="alias" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1"/>
```

But when I try to call the url(https://fortunenetworks.in:443/ourectestschool/public/users/checkToken) from postman I got below error:

```html
<head>
    <title>404 Not Found</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Not Found</h1>
    <p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
    <p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
        error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

If I tried the same url with http(http://fortunenetworks.in:443/ourectestschool/public/users/checkToken) got below msg:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Bad Request</h1>
    <p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.<br />
 Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.<br />
</p>
        <p>Additionally, a 400 Bad Request
            error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

When I use http and 8080 as port(http://fortunenetworks.in:8080/ourectestschool/public/users/checkToken) the url is working.
My controller class is:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/public/users")
public class PublicController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/checkToken",method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody
        String getCheckToken() {
            return "Success";
        }
}
```

Why is my https call is not working,what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: Try inspecting the cert in postman returned by this call - https://fortunenetworks.in/ourectestschool/public/users/checkToken Is it the one you put the JKS. Also try https://fortunenetworks.in from a browser. I suspect that a completely different web app is under https.

Comment: Maybe there is config missing on fortunenetworks.in that routes calls to ourectestschool that is in place for http but not https

Comment: https://fortunenetworks.in/ is working. i had deployed a spring boot project on appache tomcat using war file.

Comment: what is that config??where should i do that??

Comment: What were the results of the tests I suggested?

Comment: 404 not found..

Comment: If you remove the TC SSL config does https://fortunenetworks.in/ work in https?

Comment: Try inspecting the cert in postman returned by this call - fortunenetworks.in/ourectestschool/public/users/checkToken Is it the one you put the JKS?

Comment: yes.but its not jks its p12

Comment: initially we bought an SSL certificate from godaddy and installed it on domain fortunenetworks and then fortunenetworks.in starts working on https.then i added connector for port 443 in tomcat server.xml file with the keystore.p12 file for https and add ssl properties in spring boot application and deployed it on tomcat server

Comment: what u mean by 'Try inspecting the cert in postman returned by this call'.How can i inspect that??I attached the result of this call on my question

Comment: There is config missing on the main fortunenetworks.in to route https to your war file. It is in place for http. It is specific to the fortunenetworks.in platform and I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

> and the application war file has successfully deployed on tomcat
> server.Configured server.xml of tomcat as below for https:

Considering that you have a spring boot application deployed as `war` file in some existing external tomcat server, you don't need to configure the spring-boot properties for `ssl`.

So the properies defined for the above reason inside `application.yml` can be removed

You only need to configure your `server.xml` on your external tomcat you have running for `ssl` to work.

> ```
> <Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
> keystoreFile="conf/keystore.p12" keystorePass="password" keyAlias="alias" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"> sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1"/>
> ```

Make sure that everything you have configured in the above snippet is complying  (certificate, keystorePass..)

Also any modification of `server.xml` **requires tomcat restart for changes to apply**.

You can use [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/steps-to-configure-ssl-on-tomcat-and-setup-auto-redirect-from-http-to-https) as a simple example tutorial.

Then the https://fortunenetworks.in:443/ourectestschool/public/users/checkToken should become reachable.

Comment: I have installed a godaddy ssl certificate on our domain (fortunenetworks.in) and i downloded the certificate for godaddy which is a zip file contains files as 'randomhex.crt','randomhex.pem','gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt','gdig2.crt.pem' how can i generate keystore using this. I already done its but i think something is wrong there, I have mentioned it on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75255133/how-to-enable-https-using-goddady-ssl-in-a-spring-boot-application-deployed-as/75256801?noredirect=1#comment132801529_75256801 question.Did i do anything wrong on there??